# Create a custom TableView like the reminder native iOS App

Tags: ios, uitableview, native, custom-cell, reminders

I want to create a TableView like the reminder native iOS app in its design.
The tableView is simple to achieve, what I want to make is the rounded corners from the top of the cell.

What I can do it making a full rounded corners view like this:

```
// border radius
[v.layer setCornerRadius:30.0f];

// border
[v.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[v.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
```

If any one have an idea how to make only the top corners rounded, I will be grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: FYI - don't follow the accepted answer of the duplicate. The other answers are much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and yes I found my answer there :-)